# Find the value of p for which the function f(x)=$\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^{5}-3x+ln5$ decreases $\forall$x $\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

> **Question** Find the value of p for which the function f(x)=$\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^{5}-3x+ln5$ decreases
>   $\forall$x $\in\mathbb{R}$

**MY Approach**$\Longrightarrow$f'$\left(x\right)$= $\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)5x^{4}-3$$\leq$0$\Longrightarrow$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)\leq$$\frac{3}{5x^{4}}$$\Longrightarrow$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)<0$$\Longrightarrow$x $\in$$\left(-\infty,\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)$$\bigcup$
$\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{2},\infty\right)$

**But Book Says Answer is $\left[-4,\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right]$$\bigcup$$\left(1,\infty\right)$**

Comment: Since we have $\sqrt{p+4}$, we have to have $p+4\ge 0$.

Comment: It needs to be $\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)\le 0$.

Comment: @user236182 but x belong to R that does not contain infinity .so it can not be equal to zero

Comment: $\frac{3}{5x^4}>0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, therefore $\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)\le 0$.

Comment: If $\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1=0$, then $\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)\cdot 5x^4-3\lt 0,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to solve $$\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}\le 1$$
if $1-p<0$ so $1<p$ then our inequality is fulfilled.
no we assume $1-p>0$ then we have to solve
$$0\le p^2-3p-3\geq 0$$ this gives us
$$\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{21}\le p<+\infty$$ or $$-\infty<p\le \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{21}$$ as you stated

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}\le 1$$ if i square this equation i do not get the condition x belongs in (1,0) but  $$\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1}\le1-p $$ this eqaution gives  the condition x belongs in (1,0).How to know the correct approach